# NSIS concatenating part of two strings

Tags: installation, nsis, nsis-mui

I am trying to sort of merge two strings together in NSIS. I have two strings 
2.1.3.0 and 0.0.0.27269 and the string I want to create from them is 2.1.3.27269

My attempts thus far haven't worked, here is what I tried:

```
;;$VERSION      is defined with 2.1.3.0
;;$FILEVERSION2 is defined with 0.0.0.27269

;;debug
DetailPrint ${VERSION}
DetailPrint ${FILEVERSION}

;;attempt, also it doesn't say what the variables $R0-$R2 are after values 
;;copied into them, is that normal?
StrCpy $R0 ${FILEVERSION2} 5 -5
StrCpy $R1 ${VERSION} -2 
StrCpy $R2 $R1"."$R0 

DetailPrint $R2 ;;this doesn't print a value, only prints "$R2"
!define FILEVERSION3 $R2
```

Any help would be great.
Hunter

also posted here: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?p=2777308#post2777308

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate variables in NSIS you need to wrap them in quote marks.

```
;;$VERSION      is defined with 2.1.3.0
;;$FILEVERSION2 is defined with 0.0.0.27269

;;debug
DetailPrint ${VERSION}
DetailPrint ${FILEVERSION}

StrCpy $R0 ${FILEVERSION2} 5 -5
StrCpy $R1 ${VERSION} -2 

; This concatenates the strings together with a dot
StrCpy $R2 "$R1.$R0" 

DetailPrint $R2
!define FILEVERSION3 $R2
```

It also might pay to have a look through the [NSIS string functions list](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aString_Functions). Some of the functions such as the ones to get the first and last parts of strings could make your code more robust than splitting strings using hardcoded indexes.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tested this and it still doesn't work, the reason I believe is I am trying to manipulate variables created by !define. This method works for user variables. What I ended up doing was writing a small executable to pass the strings into at compile-time.